# Powershell Web Data Fetching

Tags: powershell, webrequest

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to fetch the data from URL below.

But I am not getting anything in return using the code below.

**What I want to fetch** (34) 
[image]

**Powershell Code**

```
$downloadURL     = 'https://example.html'
$downloadRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL
```

**Result**
Data not in the output code from Powershell

Comment: i would help but I cant pull up the site in its entirety, could be my proxy. Have you tried using the `Inspect` feature in windows to see which tag that number falls under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is dynamically created with JavaScript. It is hard to get the data by using `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet. Instead of that, try to use Internet Explorer COM object like this:

```
$url = 'https://example.com'
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $false
$ie.Navigate2($url)
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep 1 }
$ie.document.body.getElementsByClassName('example-class-name')::outerHTML
$ie.document.body.getElementsByClassName('example-class-name')::textContent
```

For more information, see [this article](http://irisclasson.com/2016/10/23/using-powershell-to-execute-javascript-on-a-page-and-outputting-the-result/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that info... I am getting this error.. `+ $ie.document.body.getElementsByClassName('il-customers-affected-value menu-info- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: Try to check which method is MethodNotFound by executing `$ie | Get-Member`, `$ie.document | Get-Member`, and `$ie.document.body | Get-Member`.